# How to limit max width in D3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I new to d3 bar charts and below is the code of my bar chart which I want to use in my project.

I am just wondering how can I limit max width of the bar because when I have only one record then width of bar is getting really large, actually that bar is taking entire width and then graph is not looking nice. Is there any method in d3 by which I can limit the max width of each bar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */
body { font: 12px Arial;}
path {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.legend {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-anchor: middle;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="d3id" ></div>
<!-- load the d3.js library -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var models = [
        {
            "model_name":"http://www.test.com",
            "field1":19,
            "field2":83
        },
        {
            "model_name":"http://www.test2.com",
            "field1":67,
            "field2":93
        },
        {
            "model_name":"http://www.test3.com",
            "field1":10,
            "field2":56
        },
        {
            "model_name":"http://www.test4.com",
            "field1":98,
            "field2":43
        },

        {
            "model_name":"http://www.test.com",
            "field1":19,
            "field2":83
        },
        {
            "model_name":"f7",
            "field1":67,
            "field2":93
        },
        {
            "model_name":"f8",
            "field1":10,
            "field2":56
        },
        {
            "model_name":"f9",
            "field1":98,
            "field2":43
        }
    ];
    models = models.map(i => {
        i.model_name = i.model_name;
        return i;
    });

    var container = d3.select('#d3id'),
        width = 500,
        height = 300,
        margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        barPadding = .3,
        axisTicks = {qty: 5, outerSize: 0, dateFormat: '%m-%d'};

    var svg = container
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

    var xScale0 = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]).padding(barPadding);
    var xScale1 = d3.scaleBand();
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale0).tickSizeOuter(axisTicks.outerSize);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(axisTicks.qty).tickSizeOuter(axisTicks.outerSize);

    xScale0.domain(models.map(d => d.model_name));
    xScale1.domain(['field1', 'field2']).range([0, xScale0.bandwidth()]);
    yScale.domain([0, d3.max(models, d => d.field1 > d.field2 ? d.field1 : d.field2)]);

    var model_name = svg.selectAll(".model_name")
        .data(models)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "model_name")
        .attr("transform", d => `translate(${xScale0(d.model_name)},0)`);

    /* Add field1 bars */
    model_name.selectAll(".bar.field1")
        .data(d => [d])
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar field1")
        .style("fill","#4267b2")
        .attr("x", d => xScale1('field1'))
        .attr("y", d => yScale(d.field1))
        .attr("width", xScale1.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", d => {
            return height - margin.top - margin.bottom - yScale(d.field1)
        });

    /* Add field2 bars */
    model_name.selectAll(".bar.field2")
        .data(d => [d])
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar field2")
        .style("fill","#69b3a2")
        .attr("x", d => xScale1('field2'))
        .attr("y", d => yScale(d.field2))
        .attr("width", xScale1.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", d => {
            return height - margin.top - margin.bottom - yScale(d.field2)
        });

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.top - margin.bottom})`)
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

</script>
</body>
```

Also how can I adjust the label to fit properly? please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve that by manipulating the width attribute of while appending rectangles.

Here i am checking if the width of rectangle is greater than width/10 (500/10), then keep a constant value of 50 else use default value. You can use any of your logic to manipulatee it.

```
.attr("width", function(d) {
  return xScale1.bandwidth() > width/10 ? width/10 : xScale1.bandwidth();
})
```

Please find working snippit below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */
body { font: 12px Arial;}
path {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.legend {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-anchor: middle;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="d3id" ></div>
<!-- load the d3.js library -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var models = [
        {
            "model_name":"http://www.test.com",
            "field1":19,
            "field2":83
        },
/*         {
            "model_name":"http://www.test2.com",
            "field1":67,
            "field2":93
        },
        {
            "model_name":"http://www.test3.com",
            "field1":10,
            "field2":56
        },
        {
            "model_name":"http://www.test4.com",
            "field1":98,
            "field2":43
        },
        
        {
            "model_name":"http://www.test.com",
            "field1":19,
            "field2":83
        },
        {
            "model_name":"f7",
            "field1":67,
            "field2":93
        },
        {
            "model_name":"f8",
            "field1":10,
            "field2":56
        },
        {
            "model_name":"f9",
            "field1":98,
            "field2":43
        } */
    ];
    models = models.map(i => {
        i.model_name = i.model_name;
        return i;
    });

    var container = d3.select('#d3id'),
        width = 500,
        height = 300,
        margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        barPadding = .3,
        axisTicks = {qty: 5, outerSize: 0, dateFormat: '%m-%d'};

    var svg = container
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

    var xScale0 = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]).padding(barPadding);
    var xScale1 = d3.scaleBand();
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale0).tickSizeOuter(axisTicks.outerSize);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(axisTicks.qty).tickSizeOuter(axisTicks.outerSize);

    xScale0.domain(models.map(d => d.model_name));
    xScale1.domain(['field1', 'field2']).range([0, xScale0.bandwidth()]);
    yScale.domain([0, d3.max(models, d => d.field1 > d.field2 ? d.field1 : d.field2)]);

    var model_name = svg.selectAll(".model_name")
        .data(models)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "model_name")
        .attr("transform", d => `translate(${xScale0(d.model_name)},0)`);

    /* Add field1 bars */
    model_name.selectAll(".bar.field1")
        .data(d => [d])
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar field1")
        .style("fill","#4267b2")
        .attr("x", d => xScale1('field1'))
        .attr("y", d => yScale(d.field1))
        .attr("width", xScale1.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", d => {
            return height - margin.top - margin.bottom - yScale(d.field1)
        });

    /* Add field2 bars */
    model_name.selectAll(".bar.field2")
        .data(d => [d])
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar field2")
        .style("fill","#69b3a2")
        .attr("x", d => xScale1('field2'))
        .attr("y", d => yScale(d.field2))
        .attr("width", function(d) {
          return xScale1.bandwidth() > width/2 ? width/4 : xScale1.bandwidth();
        })
        .attr("height", d => {
            return height - margin.top - margin.bottom - yScale(d.field2)
        });

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.top - margin.bottom})`)
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

</script>
</body>
```